# How do I animate the entrance of these paths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to animate the entrance of some svg paths, with no luck. Here's what I have so far:

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrPFR/1/show/)

```
$(".line").each(function(i){
        var path = $(this);

        var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
        path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength).attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .duration(1000).ease("linear").attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    });
```

I get an error "path.node is not a function".
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method on your path to get dimension

```
var w = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var h = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

You could try this

```
$(".line").each(function(i){
        var path = $(this);
        var totalLength = path.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength).attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .duration(1000).ease("linear").attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    });
```

**Edit:**

Try this way :

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/j8GJE/2/)

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
var rec = c[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var totalLength = rec.width;
```

At least you will be able to get the dimensions.

Comment: that seems to work. How do I then get animate that path, so starts from the left and expands to the right? I've got it to fade in, but it shows the entire line at once. http://jsfiddle.net/j8GJE/3/